# Как исправить ошибку? Классы и наследование

Tags: python, классы, наследование, python-3.6

выдает ошибку

```
Failed test - test_8[Nissan-t1.jpg-2.5-2.4x2.3x2].
 E   TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'passenger_seats_count'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
E   AssertionError: Тест 8. Создание экземпляра класса Truck с параметрами ('Nissan', 't1.jpg', '2.5', '2.4x2.3x2') завершается выбросом исключения TypeError.
    assert False
```

```
import csv
import os.path

TYPE_CAR = 'car'
TYPE_TRUCK = 'truck'
TYPE_SPEC_MACHINE = 'spec_machine'

class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.brand = brand
        self.carrying = float(carrying)
        
    def set_photo_file_name(self, filename):
        self.photo_file_name = filename
    def set_brand(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand
    def set_carrying(self, carrying):
        self.carrying = float(carrying)
       
    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        return os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1]

class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = int(passenger_seats_count)

    def set_passenger_seats_count(self, count):
        self.passenger_seats_count = count

class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, body_width, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count
        self.body_width = 0.0


    def set_body_width(self, width):
        self.body_width = float(width)
    def set_body_height(self, height):
        self.body_height = float(height)
    def set_body_length(self, length):
        self.body_length = float(length)
        
    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_width * self.body_height * self.body_length
        
class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)

        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count
        
    def set_extra(self, extra):
        self.extra = extra

def parse_row(row):
    brand = row[1]
    photo_file_name = row[3]
    carrying = row[5]
    if row[0] == TYPE_CAR:
        car = Car(brand, photo_file_name, carrying, row[2])
        
def get_car_list(filename):
    cars = list()
    with open(filename) as csv_fd:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_fd, delimiter=';')
        next(reader) # skip csv header
        for row in reader:
            car = parse_row(row)
            if car is not None:
                cars.append(car)

    return cars
```

Comment: Как видно тест не передаёт в Truck параметр passenger_seats_count. Либо тест неправильный, либо класс.

Comment: А вообще вы уже столько вопросов задали на такой простой проект. Неужели из текстов ошибок настолько невозможно понять в чём дело?

Comment: Я сам уже устал от этой задачи, глупая прога которая проверяет придирается ко всем мелочам

Comment: Ну вообще тесты - это нормально. Есть даже такой подход к написанию программ, когда сначала пишутся тесты, а потом сама программа, называется TDD. Просто читайте внимательно тексты ошибок, там всё написано.

Comment: Truck это же грузовик, в нем не перевозят пассажиров, так что, думаю, тест правильный. Предполагается, что в `Truck` не должно быть пассажиров.

Answer (score 0):

В строке

```
 super().__init__(TYPE_CAR, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
```

пропущен `self`

Comment: Здесь self и не нужен